# Why does Eden memory keep increasing in 64-bit JVM, but not in 32-bit JVM?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

I ran the following simple code at 32-bit JVM and 64-bit JVM, found there is no GC in 32-bit JVM but 64-bit JVM keep minor GC

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 1024 / 2];

    while (true) {
       // do nothing
    }
}
```

1. Running at **32-bit** JVM:

   **Command:**

   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe" -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:NewSize=10m -XX:MaxNewSize=10m -Xms20m -Xmx20m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 Test

   **Result**:

   The 0.5MB object is stay in Eden space, **no** gc happened

---

2. Running at **64-bit** JVM:

   **Command:**

   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe" -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:NewSize=10m -XX:MaxNewSize=10m -Xms20m -Xmx20m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 Test

   **Result**:

   Eden space keep increasing and finally triggered lots of minor GC, log looks like below:

[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 8192K->992K(9216K)] 8192K->2176K(19456K), 0.0030304 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]

[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 9184K->992K(9216K)] 10368K->2296K(19456K), 0.0019422 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]

[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 9184K->992K(9216K)] 10488K->2352K(19456K), 0.0023896 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]

[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 9184K->1008K(9216K)] 10544K->2448K(19456K), 0.0019188 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]

Heap

PSYoungGen      total 9216K, used 9051K [0x00000000ff600000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)

eden space 8192K, 98% used [0x00000000ff600000,0x00000000ffddaf00,0x00000000ffe00000)

from space 1024K, 98% used [0x00000000fff00000,0x00000000ffffc020,0x0000000100000000)

to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000000ffe00000,0x00000000ffe00000,0x00000000fff00000)

ParOldGen       total 10240K, used 1440K [0x00000000fec00000, 0x00000000ff600000, 0x00000000ff600000)

object space 10240K, 14% used [0x00000000fec00000,0x00000000fed68050,0x00000000ff600000)

Metaspace       used 8032K, capacity 8288K, committed 8448K, reserved 1056768K

class space    used 943K, capacity 984K, committed 1024K, reserved 1048576K

---

By looking at Visual GC Graphs, i found Eden space keeps increasing, I'm confused why could this happen since i only created a object with only 0.5MB? Looks like there are lots of other objects created, but what are those?

Could anybody share some knowledge? Thanks very much!

Comment: Can’t reproduce your second scenario. Of course, when you look at the JVM using Visual GC, the management code itself creates temporary objects that will eventually trigger garbage collection. This doesn’t depend on the JVM version. Did you ever try your 64Bit JVM without connecting a monitoring tool?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Holger, after i closing Visual GC, no GC happens, looks like those temporary objects created by Visual GC keep increasing the Eden space. But do you know why doesn't this happen when i run code on 32-bit JVM with Visual GC running as well?

Comment: I suppose, you’re connecting a 64Bit VisualVM installation in each case, so when you connect the 64 Bit tool with a 32 Bit JVM, certain features do not work and remain disabled. Apparently, these features are the cause for the temporary objects while the plain monitoring of the Eden fill state doesn’t cause allocations.

Comment: You're right! Tried using 32-bit VisualVM, got same result. Thanks @Holger